# How to start an start activity after android animation is over

Tags: android

How to start an activity after the animation has ended.
I have added android:oneshot="true" in the xml but how to start a new activity 
after this animation has stopped.I have attached the entire code below.
Please let me know how to start new activity.

```
    package com.appsolut.example.animation;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Animation extends Activity {

    ImageView animation;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }

    @Override

    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = 
            (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();

        if(hasFocus) {          

            frameAnimation.start();


        } else {
            frameAnimation.stop();

        }

    }


    public void onStart() {
        {
            super.onStart();

            animation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);

            animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);      

        }
    }
}
```

animation.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="true"   >

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00000" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00001" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00002" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00003" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00004" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00005" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00006" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00007" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00008" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00009" android:duration="500" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/img00010" android:duration="500" />

    </animation-list>
```

Comment: come on man, atleast try dont just ask for the answer...

Comment: Hi Mr.JoxTraex,I have tried many ways but it kept crashing or the animation just stopped I thought of attaching even that code but thought that it would complicate the process.I am new to animation in android so it will take a while ,thanks for the motivation,will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use and [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) on your animation to do whatever you want on its `onAnimationEnd()` method.

Comment: Thank you sir,but how do I channel the same code in onAnimationStart();

Comment: What do you want to do onAnimationStart() ?

Comment: Hello Mr.dtmilano.I want it to display images with  android:duration="500",how else can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

After your animation call create a new Intent (From the Intent class).

Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, newActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);

Context can be getContext() or getBaseContext()

This should work. Also dont't forget to declare your new activity in the AndroidManifest or the application will crash!

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method hasEnded() to check if ended and then if it has then call your intent to open up the new activity.

It should work

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you Sri,but I was unable to find out where to apply this solution.